# Multiple dropdowns with same options: how to remove currently selected item of one dropdown from other dropdowns?

Tags: javascript

My application has multiple `<select>` dropdowns showing exactly the same list of options. Once I select an item from one of those dropdowns, then it should remove the selected item from the other dropdowns. How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: @Asad: think of multiple exactly the same `<select><option>...</select>` elements. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: @BalusC True, but it helps when answering a question if you have to identify and explain a problem in an approach, instead of having to write the entire implementation from scratch.

Comment: You will also have a problem when an other option is selected and you need to add the previously selected one back to every select.

Comment: Don't *remove* this option, just *disable* it.

Comment: You could also use <select multiple="multiple">. With the jQuery chosen http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ plugin it will be better for multiple selection then 4-5 select boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You would identify the element's value attribute, then iterate over all select elements, iterating over all of their contents to find the one that has an identical value attribute value, finally removing the option using:

```
option.parentElement.removeChild(option);
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
    $(this).addClass('exception');
    $('option[value="' + this.value + '"]:not(.exception *)').remove();
    $(this).removeClass('exception');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PCvT4/

Which accomplishes the same thing. The problem I can foresee here is that you're going to run out of options after a few selections. You could try disabling the options, like so:

```
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
    $('option[value="disabled"]').prop('disabled',false);
    $(this).addClass('exception');
    $('option[value="' + this.value + '"]:not(.exception *)').prop('disabled',true);
    $(this).removeClass('exception');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrsC6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        var self=this;

        $("select").each(function() {
            if (this===self) {
                return;
            }

            $(this).prop('selectedIndex',0);
        });
    });
});​
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctQ5F/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
<select id="mySelect1" onclick="check(this.value)">
  <option value="2" selected disabled>select option</option>
  <option id="m1" value="0">Cats</option>
  <option id="m2" value="1">Dogs</option>
</select>
</form>

<form>
<select id="mySelect2">
    <option value="2" selected disabled>select option</option>
  <option id="m3">Cats</option>
  <option id="m4">Dogs</option>
</select>
</form>

<form>
<select id="mySelect3">
   <option value="2" selected disabled>select option</option>

  <option id="m5">Cats</option>
  <option id="m6">Dogs</option>
</select>
</form>

<form>
<select id="mySelect4">
   <option value="2" selected disabled>select option</option>

  <option id="m7">Cats</option>
  <option id="m8">Dogs</option>
</select>
</form>

<form>
<select id="mySelect5">
   <option value="2" selected disabled>select option</option>

  <option id="m9">Cats</option>
  <option id="m10">Dogs</option>
</select>
</form>

<p id="demo">hello</p>
<p id="demo2">hello2</p>


<script>
    function check(val){
//        var val=document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
        console.log(val);
        if(val==0){
            disablecats();
        }
        else if(val==1){
            disabledogs();
        }
    }
function disablecats() {



    document.getElementById("m3").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("m5").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("m7").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("m9").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("m4").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("m6").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("m8").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("m10").disabled = false;
}

function disabledogs(){

    document.getElementById("m4").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("m6").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("m8").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("m10").disabled = true;
     document.getElementById("m3").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("m5").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("m7").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("m9").disabled = false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some text explaining why is a possible solution